# NetSuite: Get Payment Instrument in Customer Record

Tags: search, suitescript2.0

I need to develop a suitelet script which accept customer id and return payment instruments information such as payment card id, memo, etc

[image of payment instrument in customer record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpcDO.png)

And this is my current script ( I don’t know how to find payment instrument so I developed it as return parent field value )

```
function onRequest(context) {
    try {
        if (context.request.method === http.Method.POST) {
            var requestBody = context.request.body;
            var customerId = JSON.parse(requestBody).customerId;
            
            var searchRec = search.create({
                type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
                filters: [
                  ['internalid', 'anyof', customerId]
                ],
                columns: [
                  search.createColumn({ name: 'parent' })
                ]
            }).run().getRange({
                start: 0,
                end: 1
            });
            
            if (searchRec.length > 0) {
                var paymentMemo = searchRec[0].getValue({
                    name: 'parent'
                });

                var resData={
                    success:"Success",
                    memo: paymentMemo
                };
                context.response.write(JSON.stringify(resData));
            } else {
                var errorRes = {
                    error: "Not found for the given customerId."
                }
                context.response.write(errorRes);
            }

        }

    } catch (e) {
        log.error('suitelet error', JSON.stringify(e));
        throw e.message;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if someone has the knowledge to solve this problem.